# Change property in child class php

Tags: php, class, oop

I want to create different classes with only one variable with different value everything else should be same as the parent class.

here is the parent class

```
class parentClass {

    private $param_name_saved = 'files';

        protected $image_objects = array();

        function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
            $this->options = array(
                'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
                'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/2',
                'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/2',
                'user_dirs' => false,
                'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
                'param_name' => $this->param_name_saved,
                'tost' => 'files',
                // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
                // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
                'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
                'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
                'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
                'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
                    'OPTIONS',
                    'HEAD',
                    'GET',
                    'POST',
                    'PUT',
                    'PATCH',
                    'DELETE'
                )
    } 
}
```

I want to create children classes with different value for property $param_name_saved

this is what I want to create

```
class childClassone extends parentClass {
        private $param_name_saved = 'files3';
}

class childClasstwo extends parentClass {
        private $param_name_saved = 'files2';
}
```

When I use the above code it doesn't what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you make `$param_name_saved` protected instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you have to change:

1. Change visibility of `parentClass::$param_name_saved` to protected.
2. Update constructors of child classes.

So:

```
class parentClass 
{
    protected $param_name_saved = 'files';
    // ...
}

class childClassone extends parentClass 
{
    function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) 
    {
        $this->param_name_saved = 'files3';
        parent::__construct($options, $initialize, $error_messages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Private properties are not visible to the children class.

You could either change the visibility to protected, or add a function setParamNameSaved on the parent class and call this function on the child class to change the property param_name_saved

Comment: Thanks I just don't know what to say - I have spent 4 hours trying to accomplish this